MATLAB Simulink for sensor less vector control mode variable frequency drive
I want to simulate 3-phase power source, SVC variable frequency drive, Induction motor using MATLAB Simulink.
MATLAB Simulink file, any description or resources I can use.
3-phase power source is connected with sensor less vector control mode frequency drive, then it should be connected to 3-phase, 690 V, 50 Hz, 1.1 MW induction motor and then impeller is connected as the load.

I think you can simulate this using "Simscape Electrical". There are various examples of SVC models here https://www.mathworks.com/help/sps/transmission-and-distribution.html?s_tid=CRUX_lftnav . There's an Induction Motor block in the "Powertrain Blockset" for Simulink: https://www.mathworks.com/help/autoblks/ref/inductionmotor.html .
